# Hyperlink in resource file

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Can I add a hyperlink in resource file Strings.resx?

I want that my string to be like this: Text example text example www.test.test.
When I click on www.test.test then the web page to open.

This behavior is for IOS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var link = "http://www.google.com";
var htmlLink = String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", link, link);

var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes()
{
     DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML
};

var nsError = new NSError();
MyTextView.ShouldInteractWithUrl += delegate
{
     return true;
};
MyTextView.Editable = false;
MyTextView.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(htmlLink, attr, ref nsError);
```

Comment: This works for Xamarin.Forms. I have Xamarin.IOS.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check if this helps. Source : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38917/make-hyperlinks-in-uilabel-clickable

Comment: Yes, this is ok for UITextView but I want to work withh UILabel

Comment: How do I edit htmlLink  to have my own style?